# How to make the selected item in the listbox on the view

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a listbox in aspx page. When the page load, I set locationID on hidden field and set it is selected on the listbox. Since there are many items on the listbox. I would like to show the selected item on the view when the page is not postback. however scrollintoview is only for element.  I found some example on the web but it is show on the top.My code doesn't work. Would someone tell me how to show the selected item on the view. Thanks in advance.

There is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

        $(document).ready(scrollLocation);

        function scrollLocation() {
          var offset = 0;
            var selectedIndex = $("#listLocation")[0].selectedIndex;
            alert(selectedIndex);
            $("#listLocation option").each(function (i, e) {
                if (i == selectedIndex) return false;
                offset += $(e).height();
            });
            $("#listLocation").scrollTop(offset);

        }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `offset()` add up the `height`s of the `option`s until the selected one, then `scrollTop()`. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h226p90k/

**HTML**

```
<select id="s1" size="5">
    <option value='1'>1<option>
    <option value='2'>2<option>
    <option value='3'>3<option>
    <option value='4'>4<option>
    <option value='5'>5<option>
    <option value='6'>6<option>
    <option value='7'>7<option>
    <option value='8'>8<option>
    <option value='9' selected='selected'>9<option>
    <option value='10'>10<option>  
    <option value='11'>11<option> 
    <option value='12'>12<option> 
    <option value='13'>13<option> 
    <option value='14'>14<option> 
    <option value='15'>15<option> 
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var offset = 0;  

    // Find the selected index
    var selectedIndex = $("#s1")[0].selectedIndex;
    $("#s1 option").each(function(i,e){             
        // if this is the selected one, stop
        if(i==selectedIndex) return false;
        // otherwise add up
        offset += $(e).height();    
    });    

    $("#s1").scrollTop(offset);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I put your code into my function. However, the selected item is not in the view. I have to scroll down to see it. Do I misunderstand your code?

Comment: I put the alert to show the value of the offset. It is 0